# What's the correct Try Exception for NoneType when using regex's .groups() function

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7, nonetype, try-except

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
try:
    clean = filter(None, re.match(r'^(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)$', full).groups())
except TypeError:
    clean = ""
```

However I get the following traceback...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 116, in <module>
    clean = filter(None, re.match(r'^(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)$', full).groups())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

What is the correct exception / correct way around this problem?

Comment: Usually `re` match throws `AttributeError` if no match is found

Comment: @SivaCn, no... It returns `None`. OP then tries to access the `groups` attribute of the returned value, i.e. of `None`. Hence the `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`re.match` returns `None` if it cannot find a match.  Probably the cleanest solution to this problem is to just do this:

```
# There is no need for the try/except anymore
match = re.match(r'^(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)$', full)
if match is not None:
    clean = filter(None, match.groups())
else:
    clean = ""
```

Note that you could also do `if match:`, but I personally like to do `if match is not None:` because it is clearer.  "Explicit is better than implicit" remember. ;)

Answer (score 23):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 116, in <module>
    clean = filter(None, re.match(r'^(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)$', full).groups())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

It tells you what error is to handle: AttributeError

The, it is either:

```
try:
    clean = filter(None, re.match(r'^(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)$', full).groups())
except AttributeError:
    clean = ""
```

or

```
my_match = re.match(r'^(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)$', full)
my_match = ''
if my_match is not None:
     clean = my_match.groups()
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
clean = ""
regex =  re.match(r'^(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)$', full)
if regex:
    clean = filter(None, regex.groups())
```

The problem is, `re.match(r'^(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)$', full)` returns a `None` if it does not find a match. Hence the error.

Note: You do not require a `try..except` if you handle it this way.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `AttributeError` to your exception clause.

An except clause may name multiple exceptions as a parenthesized tuple:

```
try:
    clean = filter(None, re.match(r'^(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)$', full).groups())
except (TypeError, AttributeError):
    clean = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I think handling AttributeError using try, catch is a much cleaner solution.
It may so happen that any transformation on performed the row may be a very expensive operation. For e.g.

```
match = re.match(r'^(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)$', full)
```

if match is not None:
    clean = filter(None, match.groups())
else:
    clean = ""

in the above case, the structure of the row changed in such a way that the regex delivered partial result. So, now  match will not be none and the AttributeError exception will be thrown.